# encrypting password in shell script linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, password-encryption, mongodump

I'm using a user and password combo in an automated shell script to run a command on MongoDB.
The username and password are currently in plaintext. I'm trying to figure out a way to encrypt the password in another file/another way.

I've seen people suggest using openssl but I don't understand how it helps.

You encrypt the password file using a password, but that is also clearly shown in the shell script. How is that not going back to square one?

Comment: You can prevent the user who runs the script from being able to _read_ the script if the script is owned by a dedicated user, has 0700 permissions, and is accessed via a privilege escalation path that discards environment variables during execution. But don't store passwords in scripts at all -- asymmetric key authentication is the way to go; using the privilege escalation approach is still useful when doing that to restrict access to the relevant key.

Comment: Another approach is to provide access to the database server via a UNIX domain socket accessed through a path with restricted filesystem permissions.

Comment: Anyhow, all this discussion of better strategies would be more on topic at [security.se] Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`--tls` or the `--ssl` flag](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/): A public/private key combo is *not* an encrypted password, encrypting a password with a password would definitely not be any secure here (even though it can be useful sometime). If you've never heard of asymmetric cryptography before I encourage you to learn about it, it's a very useful tool.

You will need to create a public and a private key for your user (using openssl is probably the most documented way), add the public key to the mongodb server and use the `--tlsCertificateKeyFile` flag to use the private key in your mongosh command line.

You could encrypt the private key with a password but since it would have to be in plain text in your script, in this case you could do without, just don't forget to make the private key accessible only to the user that runs the script and to make sure this user is secure.

Comment: First of all thank you for your detailed answer but I think I either didn't understand or didn't completely explain my procedure.


I'm going to be running a shell script from within the Mongo server itself which will connect to the MongoDB.
In that script I will provide authentication to the DB itself. That's the part I want to be able to do with anything but a plain text password.

Comment: @NetanelPeretz so you have a Linux server running both a mangodb server and a bash script that accesses the mongodb server through mangosh, did I get that right?

Answer (score 0):

If you run automated shell script, then it will be difficult, because at certain point you need to store the password.

You can store the password in a config file (could be the `~/.bashrc` file). Make this file accessible only for appropriate users! Then use the password from variable, e.g. `${MONGO_PASSWORD}`

Note, for `mongodump` and similar tools you should use the new [--config](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--config) option for username/password. Otherwise, every user can get the password as clear text with simple `ps -ef | grep mongo` command.